# Avoiding Overwriting Existing Cron Jobs

Tags: cron, cron-task

**Background**

I need to add a `cron job` to a server that has a bunch of other `cron jobs` on it. I have never done this before so I want to make sure I do it without affecting any other `cron jobs`.

I read in a tutorial [here](https://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

> You can add more schedules the same way. Put all your different
>   schedules into a single crontab file. The first line should be your
>   MAILTO line, followed by each schedule/command on a separate line.
>   When you run "crontab crontab.txt" later, crontab will replace your
>   existing schedule with the schedules in your new crontab.txt.

It sounds like it will replace any `cron jobs` in that file but I want to be sure it does not overwrite all `cron jobs` and set the new schedule to the newest file installed.

**Question**

So to be clear. If I have existing cron jobs on a server and I create a new `cron.txt` file that has new `cron jobs` in it. Will it install the `cron jobs` in the new file and leave the existing cron jobs which are in other cron job files unchanged so they will continue to work as they have been?

**Example**

Runs everyday at 9:30am

*NewCronJobs.txt*

```
MAILTO=email@example.com
30 9 * * * /root/path/to/php/file/to/run/script.php >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your own crontab, so you should be able to modify it without messing up anybody else's jobs.  Try this, in your terminal type

```
crontab -e
```

If you see cron jobs already listed, then do not change them.  If not, then you are starting from a blank slate.  Regardless of whether you see other cron jobs or not you can always add your task to the bottom or the current crontab file.  Provided your php script is not faulty you will be able to test your cron job without adversely affecting anything on the server.

Comment: I was planning on placing the file on the server and then running it with crontab crontab.txt. You are saying do it a different way? Yes there are for sure other cron jobs on the server. It is a VPS we own and I Just don't want to break anything by adding my own crontab file. Sorry but to be clear you are saying if I add my own cron job file and run crontab crontab.txt it will schedule my new cron jobs and wont affect the existing ones at all?

Comment: I do not know about adding a new crontab.txt file.  Every user should have his own cron file already.  This can be edited by running "crontab -e" from the terminal.  Do all of your editing from here and you will be fine (unless your cron jobs do something stupid like "rm -rf /").